# Setting and retrieving environmental variables in flask applications

Tags: python, docker, flask, environment-variables

I want to build a very simple REST api using python3/flask.

Say for example I want to set my `SECRET_KEY` required by `flask` as env var.

What is the recommended way of going about it?

I am aware of `python-dotenv` package that allows (or should I say **requires**?) the `.flaskenv` file with env vars set as key-value pairs in the form of

```
SECRET_KEY="my_secret_key"
DB_NAME="mydatabase"
```

etc.

Then (I assume) I can create a `settings.py` file such as

```
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY`)
```

and then perform an `import settings` on my flask files and so on.

My main question is how can this be adapted in a containerized environment where there will not be such an `.flaskenv` file but the respective variables will be available as runtime env vars in the container itself (say via its orchestrator)

Will the above form of `settings.py` be able to retrieve env vars in the absence of `.flaskenv`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`python-dotenv` actually has nothing to do with Flask. It is for your `.env` file to be translated into actual env variables. So if you're going to have actual env variables without it, your `os.getenv` should still work.

Sidenote: You can also use `os.environ`:

```py
os.environ.get("SECRET")
```

Comment: This worked for me! I also had to load the environment variables. I had to add

`load_dotenv()`  into my code

Answer (score 9):

Set your environment variable in the interpreter:

```
export SECRET_KEY=123
```

Call the variable with `environ.get()`:

```
from os import environ
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Answer (score 0):

> My main question is how can this be adapted in a containerized
> environment where there will not be such an .flaskenv file but the
> respective variables will be available as runtime env vars in the
> container itself?

`python-dov` just a easy way to setup environment variables.

> Will the above form of settings.py be able to retrieve env vars in the
> absence of .flaskenv?

If you are in containerized environment, you have to also set env variables in there. I would recommend to use [`from_prefixed_env`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Config.from_prefixed_env), i.e. `app.config.from_prefixed_env()`. This will loads all env variables starting with `FLASK` and remove the prefix `FLASK_` into your app config, e.g., `FLASK_DEBUG` would be `DEBUG` in this way.