# hidding password and login

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongodb-atlas

Is there a way to hide my password for database access in my MongoDB atlas?  Am using flask and mongoengine as the ODM.

````
user = os.getenv['username']
pass = os.getenv['passdb']
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-lcotk.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test ```
````

Comment: Could you clarify the question? In the example your password is coming from an env variable so you simply need to use it dynamically in the `MongoClient` and the actual password won't appear in your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting and retrieving environmental variables in flask applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529391/setting-and-retrieving-environmental-variables-in-flask-applications)

Comment: it does answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for env variable, I was working with nodejs and having the some issue, I find out that there's a library called dotenv where you can setup a env variable file separated from other files and then you can hide all you secrets variable.